# AngularJS Restangular and get a single url

Tags: angularjs, rest

I have these "methods" in my angular service that use restangular to get remote data where the respose is this:

```
{
"1105":{"title":"","field_nazione":{"und":[{"value":null,"format":null,"safe_value":""}]},"field_redazionale":{"und":[{"value":null}]}},
"1110":{"title":"","field_nazione":{"und":[{"value":null,"format":null,"safe_value":""}]},"field_redazionale":{"und":[{"value":null}]}}
}; 


function restfulService(ipCookie,Restangular) {
        return {
            //Setta la directory di partenza del service rest. In questo modo non devo sempre definirlo
            restfulBase : function() {
                return Restangular.oneUrl('rest','http://MYREMOTEHOST/rest');
            },

            getAllCity : function () {
                return this.restfulBase().get('cities', {'all':1}, {}, {'X-CSRF-Token': tokenVar});
            },
            ....
};
```

Why when I call getAllCity() the url is :

```
http://MYDOMAIN/rest?0=c&1=i&2=t&3=i&4=e&5=s
```

?

If I use this :

```
Restangular.oneUrl('rest','http://MYDOMAIN/rest/cities').get({all : 1});
```

I have no problems.

I have tried changing my app to set Restangular.setBaseUrl() in .config() method and then changing my service to use Restangular.all('cities').get() but I have an error about "strings".

If I use getAll() I have an error about "getLists() want array and not objects".

So: which is the correct way to use Restangular ? I have read online documentation and tutorial, but I have not understand how to retrieve elements in the right way. And to "post".

Thanks and sorry for this stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you set your base as "one" type of resource. The "one" method is not for setting the base urls. The way I set the base url is like this:

```
angular.module('app')
   .config(['RestangularProvider', function (RestangularProvider) {

        // Set the base URL
        RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://MYREMOTEHOST/rest');    
    }]);
```

And then I access each resource, depending on its type with "one" or "all", like so:

```
function restfulService(ipCookie,Restangular) {
        return {
            getAllCity : function () {
                return Restangular.all('cities').getList();
            },
            ....
};
```

You can also set the default params in the config phase, or per request at runtime.
The *"getLists() want array and not objects"* error you get when you use "all" is because it accepts only arrays as a response, therefore you need to intercept the data before and parse it in an array. In your case, you are getting an object, so you can parse it like this:

```
    // this happens at runtime, either in your implementation code or in a more global config file, like:

   Restangular.addResponseInterceptor(function (data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {
    // If the what is set, than just grab it and return it
          if (data.hasOwnProperty(what)) {
               return data[what];
          } else {
               // Otherwise make it an array
               var arr = [];
               for (var key in data) {
                   arr.push(data[key]);
               }
               return arr;
         });
```

Hope this helps.